# Install Data is not executed in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, category-attribute, installdata

I am trying to create a category attribute:
This is my file form `Vendor/Module/Setup:`

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $categorySetupFactory;

    public function __construct(CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory)
    {
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $categorySetup->addAttribute(
            Category::ENTITY,
            'content_category_page',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'label' => 'Content Page',
                'input' => 'select',
                'sort_order' => 100,
                'source' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Page',
                'global' => 2,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => null,
                'group' => 'General Information',
                'backend' => ''
            ]
        );
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

The current version of the module is 1.0.1, so I increased it to 1.0.2 and run the `setup:upgrade`. After the module is updated to version 1.0.2 in the `setup_module` table, but my InstallData is not executed and the attribute is missing . Not sure what I am doing wrong here? Would you please advice ?

Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an UpgradeData class in Setup. Here is an example

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * UpgradeData constructor.
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     */
    public function upgrade(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.2', '<')) {
            
          // upgrade attribute data here

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnx, it works!